# MAX Date with a where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have the following query:

```
SELECT
    cst_recno as [Member ID],
    cmc_end_date as 'Last Term End date as a Trustee',
    ind_first_name as 'Last Name',
    ind_mid_name as 'First Name',
    ind_last_name as 'Last Name',
    cst_ixo_title_dn as 'title',
    cst_org_name_dn as 'organization',
    adr_country as 'Country',
    adr_city as 'City',
    adr_state as 'State',
    cst_eml_address_dn as 'Email'
FROM mb_committee_x_customer  
JOIN co_customer ON cst_key=cmc_cst_key 
JOIN mb_committee ON cmt_key=cmc_cmt_key 
JOIN co_individual ON ind_cst_key=cmc_cst_key 
LEFT JOIN co_customer_x_address ON cmc_cxa_key=cxa_key 
LEFT JOIN co_address ON cxa_adr_key = adr_key 
WHERE cmc_end_date <= '9/6/2017' 
AND ind_deceased_flag != 1 
AND cmt_code = N'T'
ORDER BY cst_recno
```

returning this sample Data:

```
MemberID    Last Term End Date as a Trustee         Last Name
1004        2003-06-30                              Smith
1004        2005-06-30                              Smith
1004        2006-06-30                              Smith
1004        2008-06-30                              Smith
1004        2007-06-30                              Smith
```

I would like to get the oldest date for each member id, so my result set looks like this:

```
MemberID    Last Term End Date as a Trustee         Last Name
1004        2008-06-30                              Smith
```

Comment: Where does the `cmc_end_date ` field live? You didn't put table aliases in the question

Comment: I'll echo Eli. Where do these fields come from? Aliases make for much cleaner code. Also, does cmt_code contain UNICODE characters? Is that field an nvarchar or nchar? If not, there's no need to cast the value with N''.

Answer (score 5):

Use `ROW_NUMBER()` to identify the latest record for each `memberID` :

```
SELECT t.* 
FROM(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY s.memberID ORDER BY cmc_end_date DESC) as rnk,
            cst_recno as [Member ID],
            cmc_end_date as 'Last Term End date as a Trustee',
            ind_first_name as 'Last Name',
            ind_mid_name as 'First Name',
            ind_last_name as 'Last Name',
            cst_ixo_title_dn as 'title',
            cst_org_name_dn as 'organization',
            adr_country as 'Country',
            adr_city as 'City',
            adr_state as 'State',
            cst_eml_address_dn as 'Email'
     FROM mb_committee_x_customer  
     JOIN co_customer ON cst_key=cmc_cst_key 
     JOIN mb_committee ON cmt_key=cmc_cmt_key 
     JOIN co_individual ON ind_cst_key=cmc_cst_key 
     LEFT JOIN co_customer_x_address ON cmc_cxa_key=cxa_key 
     LEFT JOIN co_address ON cxa_adr_key = adr_key 
     WHERE cmc_end_date <= '9/6/2017' AND ind_deceased_flag != 1 AND cmt_code = N'T') t
WHERE t.rnk = 1
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: I like window functions. They're very efficient and can be very flexible.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [GROUP BY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-group-by-transact-sql):

```
SELECT
       cst_recno as [Member ID],
       MAX(cmc_end_date) as 'Last Term End date as a Trustee',
       ind_first_name as 'Last Name',
       ind_mid_name as 'First Name',
       ind_last_name as 'Last Name',
       cst_ixo_title_dn as 'title',
       cst_org_name_dn as 'organization',
       adr_country as 'Country',
       adr_city as 'City',
       adr_state as 'State',
       cst_eml_address_dn as 'Email'
FROM 
         mb_committee_x_customer  
    JOIN co_customer ON cst_key=cmc_cst_key 
    JOIN mb_committee ON cmt_key=cmc_cmt_key 
    JOIN co_individual ON ind_cst_key=cmc_cst_key 
    LEFT JOIN co_customer_x_address ON cmc_cxa_key=cxa_key 
    LEFT JOIN co_address ON cxa_adr_key = adr_key 
WHERE cmc_end_date <= '9/6/2017' AND ind_deceased_flag != 1 AND cmt_code = N'T'
GROUP BY cst_recno, ind_first_name, ind_mid_name, ind_last_name, cst_ixo_title_dn,cst_org_name_dn,adr_country,adr_city,adr_state,cst_eml_address_dn
ORDER BY cst_recno
```

Comment: works in this case. but what if any other column of the select changed between the dates? like a title is added.

Comment: I'm not even sure it works in this case.. Maybe the OP only simplified it for us, we saw only 3 columns out of 11. @EstebanP.

Comment: We need to ask the OP if that can be the case. This is the solution based on sample data and desired result. In that case one way would be to have a result set with the maximum date for each `memberId` and then to join the existing query with that result set on `memberId` and `max_cmc_end_date` or @sagi's way using the row number function :)

Comment: The rest of the columns are identical. The only difference was in the end cmc_end_date column. I used the group by and max function and it worked great. I don't know what I was doing before that it didn't work before. Thank you all for the comments

Answer (score -1):

This may work better for performance, something to consider -

Assuming the first query performs nicely, you may want to throw that resultset into a temp table, then run a query grouping that data off of the temp table. Indexes can be added to that temp table if need be. But the below should work.

```
SELECT cst_recno as [Member ID],
       cmc_end_date as 'Last Term End date as a Trustee',
       ind_first_name as 'Last Name',
       ind_mid_name as 'First Name',
       ind_last_name as 'Last Name',
       cst_ixo_title_dn as 'title',
       cst_org_name_dn as 'organization',
       adr_country as 'Country',
       adr_city as 'City',
       adr_state as 'State',
       cst_eml_address_dn as 'Email'
  INTO #tempTable
  FROM mb_committee_x_customer  
  JOIN co_customer 
    ON cst_key=cmc_cst_key 
  JOIN mb_committee 
    ON cmt_key=cmc_cmt_key 
  JOIN co_individual 
    ON ind_cst_key=cmc_cst_key 
  LEFT JOIN co_customer_x_address 
    ON cmc_cxa_key=cxa_key 
  LEFT JOIN co_address 
    ON cxa_adr_key = adr_key 
 WHERE cmc_end_date <= '9/6/2017' 
   AND ind_deceased_flag != 1 
   AND cmt_code = N'T'
 ORDER BY cst_recno

;WITH CTE ([Last Term End date as a Trustee], [Last Name])
AS
 (SELECT MAX([Last Term End date as a Trustee]),                
        [Last Name]
   FROM #tempTable
  GROUP BY [Last Name])

SELECT tt.[Member ID],
       c.[Last Term End date as a Trustee],
       c.[Last Name]
  FROM CTE c
  JOIN #tempTable tt
    ON c.[Last Term End date as a Trustee] = tt.[Last Term End date as a Trustee]
   AND c.[Last Name] = tt.[Last Name]
```